# Installation problem with gotools extension for Ghidra: Extension version for [gotools-master.zip] is incompatible with Ghidra

Tags: ghidra, go

I'm getting the following error when I try to install the following extension https://github.com/felberj/gotools

> Installation Error
>
> Extension version for [gotools-master.zip] is incompatible with Ghidra.

```
Build Date: 2022-Jan-25 1526 EST
Ghidra Version: 10.1..2
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.9.7-7-hotspot
JVM Version: Microsoft 17.9.7
OS: Windows 11 10.0 amd64
Workstation: 192.168.1.128
```

[image: screenshot of error]

I followed the instructions in the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/felberj/gotools/blob/master/README.md) yet the extension doesn't appear in the extensions tab, when I try to manually add it I get the message above that Ghidra doesn't support this extension. I'm using the version that is described in readme which is Ghidra 10.1.2. Can anyone assess the problem I'm encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug upstream you can see it filed as [issue #9 on Github](https://github.com/felberj/gotools/issues/9). According to one of the posters, there is a release that works on this fork,

https://github.com/sophieboyle/gotools/releases